# how can I use JavaScript to wait for a click on one page then take data stored in an array with objects to display it's content on another page

Tags: javascript, html

the site that I am building will have two separate pages. One page will be used as a service gallery with links and the other page will be used to upload the content that is selected from the service gallery via JavaScript. the JavaScript has an array with objects. the content in the object will load onto the other page via the elements it selects. so if a user wants to know more about a service they will click the link the event listener will listen for a click. then the script will check what service is selected and load that data witch is specific to the service. the other page will have div's that javascript will use to append created elements.
somewhere in my code I can not figure out what to do next... so I'm reaching out to stackoverflow with hopes to find someone that had accomplished this already. I'll also post portions of my code to help understand my question.

the JavaScript:

please note that I used the event object to prevent the default action of the anchor tag so it will allow me to see what element was selected on the DOM. I also removed the created element and put the console.log() to run some bug tests...

```
(function () {
    // DYNAMIC PAGE LOADING FOR PAGE DESCRIPTION
    const description = [
        {
            page: "garden",
            hero: "GARDEN",
            title: "Garden Care",
            title_para: "this will be some dummy text for now",
            title_image: "../asset/img/img1.jpg",

            icon: "",
            links: {},
            sideImage1: "",
            sideBox1: "",
            sideImage2: "",
            sideBox2: "",

            mainTitle: "",
            mainPara1: "",
            mainPara2: "",
            mainImage1: "",
            mainImage2: "",
            mainImage3: "",

            sub_mainTitle: "",
            sub_mainPara1: "",
            sub_mainPara2: "",
            sub_mainImage1: "",
            sub_mainImage2: "",
            sub_mainImage3: ""
        },
    ]

    let serviceDescription = document.getElementsByClassName("service-description");

    for (let i = 0; i < serviceDescription.length; i++) {
        serviceDescription[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (serviceDescription[i] == serviceDescription[0]) {
                let elHeading = document.getElementById("hero-text");
                console.log(elHeading);
            }
        }, false);
    }

}());
```

the html

```html
<!-- this page is the service gallery and each link listens for a click -->

         <div class="service-gallery-container">
            <div class="service-gallery-card">
               <a href="description.php" class="service-description">
                  <div class="service-gallery-image-box service-gallery-image-1"></div>
               </a>
               <h2 class="font-green">GARDEN</h2>
               <p>Lean more about our garden servies</p>
            </div><!-- end of servcie card 1 -->
            <div class="service-gallery-card">
               <a href="description.php" class="service-description">
                  <div class="service-gallery-image-box service-gallery-image-2"></div>
               </a>
               <h2 class="font-green">LAWN</h2>
               <p>Lean more about our lawn servies</p>
            </div><!-- end of servcie card 2 -->
        </div>

<!-- this page is the template that JavaScript will use to load in the content from the object -->

    <section class="description-path hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="hero-content">
                <h1 id="hero-text" class="hero-text">Description</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- end of description path hero -->

    <section class="description-heading">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="description-title"></div>
            <div id="description-image"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- end of description heading -->
```

I hope this helps, if you need more information please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share arrays, object, and any kind of data between pages I would suggest using [localStorage](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjJzaC9mfLsAhVKRBoKHbSoCNEQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FWindow%2FlocalStorage&usg=AOvVaw2AmRi2if_HfOObD3GES5FE) with JSON to [stringfiy and parse](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjxncL5mfLsAhVMzoUKHYQiAf8QFjABegQIChAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fjavascript-in-plain-english%2Fhow-to-use-stringify-and-parse-in-javascript-6b637b571a32%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3Das%2520a%2520pair.-%2CJSON.%2Cit%2520into%2520a%2520JavaScript%2520object.&usg=AOvVaw3lzqEHGVFQ-zKANc-LwFNg) the data.

for example:

```js
// you currently at page www.sitename.com/

// the data you want to take to the other page, for this example I use array but as I say you can use whatever you need
let array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];

// now we need to convert 'array' to normal string so we can save it inside 'localStorage'
// we will do this using JSON.stringify
let stringArray = JSON.stringify(array);

// now we ready to save the data inside localStorage
localStorage.setItem("myArray", stringArray);
```

After this step, lets say the client goes now to 'www.sitename.com/product':

```js
// get the data we stored inside localStorage
let data = localStorage.getItem("myArray");

// now we need to convert our data to normal js array
let normalArray = JSON.pars(data);

// now you ready to use your array and do whatever you want
console.log(normarArray[0]) // output 'item1'
```

Please **BE CARFUL** and don't use this approach to store any sensitive information like client's password or credit card as it's possible to any one to access these data very easily.

Comment: I never would of thought about using local storage! after I test your suggestion I'll report my results, I hope it works